# TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page to load

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, robotframework, microsoft-edge

I want to Open browser in Edge with IE mode.
My environment: IE7, windows 11, Python 3.10.4, Edge version 108.0.1462.46
And I follow the required configuration from below:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/

1. I made the same value for Enhanced Protected Mode by setting the REG_DWORD 2500 value to 0 in Zones 0,1,2,3,4:
   Registry Editer path: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones
2. I add the IEDriverServer to my PATH

Is there any wrong steps about my configuration?

Below is my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${IEDriver}  D:\\IEDriver\\64bits\\IEDriverServer.exe

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test
    Open Browser  https://www.google.com.tw/  ie  executable_path=${IEDriver}  options=ignore_zoom_level=True; attach_to_edge_chrome=True; edge_executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
    Maximize Browser Window
```

After I executing my code, I can open google in Edge with IE mode, but after that web page stuck and always get thie error message:
TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page to load.

Answer (score 0):

This option may work for you in Windows 11 IE mode automation. Check it out:

```
ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
```

**UPDATE**

Or you can simply try setting the page load timeout according to your requirement:

```
*** Variables ***
${orig timeout}    15 seconds
*** Test Cases ***
Example Test
    Set Selenium Timeout    ${orig timeout}
```

If the element you'd like to interact with has been fully loaded, you can skip the page loading and continue. A native Python example:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
try:
   driver.get('https://google.com')
except TimeoutException:
    print
    '!!!!!!time out after 10 seconds!!!!!!'
    driver.execute_script("window.stop()")
```

In Robot Framework:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example Test
    Set Selenium Timeout    ${orig timeout}
    TRY
        Open Browser    https://www.google.com    ie    options=ignore_zoom_level=True; attach_to_edge_chrome=True; edge_executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
    EXCEPT    '!!!!!!time out after 10 seconds!!!!!!'
        Execute Javascript    window.stop()
    END
    Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this option did not help.. (I also tried ignore_protected_mode_settings = False)

Comment: @ChangYo I've found another solution that may work by setting the page load timeout. I've updated my answer and please check it.

Comment: I try to add this command (Set Selenium Timeout    ${orig timeout}) before/after Open Browser, it seems like this command does not take any effect. Also I find that the Edge page which opened by my code did not have the same web setting as I open it by myself. (BTW, I can not open setting in Edge which opened by my code)

Comment: It seems like driver did not think page finish loading. Because I moved the print command after the driver.execute_script("window.stop()"), it did not print and showed two more error message: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Comment: @ChangYo The error message is often related to the incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using. You can try other versions of IE driver for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

And I found something interesting: I use python and selenium and below is my code:

```
ieOptions = webdriver.IeOptions()
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgechromium", True)
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgepath",'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe')
driver = webdriver.Ie(options=ieOptions)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

If I remove this line "driver.get('https://google.com')" and my code runs perfectly.
But If I add it back, the page will go to goole and stuck there (It means that this code will not do driver.quit()

Comment: I also try to switch "driver.maximize_window()" and "driver.get('https://google.com')". Every command will stop after driver.get('https://google.com')

Comment: Does it only apply to Google but works on other sites? If the element you'd like to interact with has been loaded, you can manually skip the page loading and continue. I've updated another workaround. Please check it.

Comment: It not only apply to Google, I also try youtube and others.